# Teams Task/Tab SSO Issue on IOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.
And we're adding a tab to our bot app and we use SSO to authenticate users.

Here's an example of our project pages:

```
main.project.com - main page where users do their job.
auth.project.com - the page where users authenticate with SSO.
```

By default we open "main.project.com" and check if user is authenticated. If user is not authenticated we redirect them to "auth.project.com", they authenticate there and we redirect them back to "main.project.com" afterwards.

This works perfectly on all platforms except IOS.
On IOS we have the `App is neither whitelisted nor app resource matches current domain` error.

We've made an investigation and it seems like SSO library (on IOS) doesn't check current location on the webView, instead it checks the very first location of the tab app.

Our SSO api address is "**api://auth.project.com/{...appID is truncated...}**" and we get SSO token from the page with this location.
If we open the TAB with "auth.project.com" as a first page of the tab, we can auth user without any issues.

Is this expected, does it work as intended?

```
Phone:
    iPhone SE
    IOS version 15.1

Microsoft Teams App
    Version: 4.8.1
    Build: 4.8.77.2022083005/0511 (general)
    Calling Version: 2022.13.01.6
    Release Branch: 2022Apr-T2
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted the domain in the `validDomains` section of the manifest? And are you using Teams SSO (as in `microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken`) or msal directly?

Comment: @ScottPerham yes, both domains are in the whitelist and yes we're using getAuthToken to get the token. So basically it's the same as in "how to", except that one redirect before that actual getAuthToken execution.

Comment: @Oleksa - Are you still facing the issue or it has resolved?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Yes, we're still having the issue. We did workaround however, but the issue is still there.

Comment: @Oleska-  Could you please share the demo account to try this and debug this?
you can share the details here-microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com